# Symfony: убрать сессии для аутентификатора

Tags: symfony

Имеется обычный аутентификатор `form_login` и кастомный для авторизации по ключу в headers. При авторизации через второй аутентификатор создается сессия и так происходит при каждом запросе. Если в security.yaml выставить `stateless: true`, то тогда не будет пускать пользователей с `form_login` аутентификатора. Как сделать так, чтобы сессии не сохранялись только при авторизации через API ключ?

security.yaml:

```
security:
    enable_authenticator_manager: true
    encoders:
        App\Entity\User:
            algorithm: auto
    providers:
        app_user_provider:
            entity:
                class: App\Entity\User
                property: username
    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main:
            lazy: true
            provider: app_user_provider
            form_login:
                login_path: app_login
                check_path: app_login
                default_target_path: /
            custom_authenticators:
                - App\Security\TokenAuthenticator
            entry_point: form_login
            logout:
                path: app_logout
```

Важно сохранить сессии для `form_login` и убрать их для `TokenAuthenticator`, т.к. возможно обращение к endpoint'ам разными способами. Аутентификатор сделан по этой [статье](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/experimental_authenticators.html#creating-a-custom-authenticator).

Comment: Мне кажется самым простым способом будет разделить разные методы авторизации на разные фаерволы

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На данный момент пришлось отказаться от стандартных сессий, которые генерируются Symfony. Вместо этого, в обоих случаях я использую токен, но в одном я его записываю в cookie, в другом - использую в заголовке. Токен генерируется в контроллерах.

```
security:
    enable_authenticator_manager: true
    encoders:
        App\Entity\User:
            algorithm: auto

    providers:
        app_user_provider:
            entity:
                class: App\Entity\User
                property: username
    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main:
            lazy: true
            provider: app_user_provider
            custom_authenticators:
                - App\Security\TokenHeaderAuthenticator
                - App\Security\TokenCookieAuthenticator
            stateless: true
```